# Sendgrid PHP API v3 Contact List Update Error

Tags: php, forms, api, sendgrid

Trying to create a custom contact form using Sendgrid API to add the recipient to a contact list, following the example from https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/contactdb/contactdb.php, currently I have:

```
require("sendgrid-php.php");

// Send an Email
$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "info@test.com");
$subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid PHP Library!";
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, "my@email.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = 'API_GOES_HERE';
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$list_id = "12345";
$recipient_id = base64_encode("test@email.com");
$listResponse = $sg->client->contactdb()->lists()->_($list_id)->recipients()->_($recipient_id)->post();
echo $listResponse->statusCode();
echo $listResponse->body();
echo $listResponse->headers();
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
**message":"Recipient ID does not exist"**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what the documentation doesn't say is that the user has to exist first in SendGrid to be added to a contact list.

So the steps are:

1. Create the recipient
2. Send the recipient an Email
3. Add the recipient to a contact list

Here's my working code in case anyone needs it so that you won't spend hours on this like I did:

```
// Get SendGrid credentials
require("sendgrid-php.php");
$apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

// Only process POST requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace
    $array[0]['first_name'] = strip_tags(trim($_POST['first-name']));
    $array[0]['last_name'] = strip_tags(trim($_POST['last-name']));
    $array[0]['email'] = filter_var(trim($_POST['user-email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $firstName = strip_tags(trim($_POST['first-name']));
    $lastName = strip_tags(trim($_POST['last-name']));
    $recipient = filter_var(trim($_POST['user-email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);  

    // Create the recipient in SendGrid (part I was missing)
    $recipientResponse = $sg->client->contactdb()->recipients()->post($array);

    // Build the email
    $from = new SendGrid\Email('Company Name', "example@company.com");
    $subject = "Subject";
    $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $recipient);
    $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", YOUR HTML TEMPLATE CODE HERE);

    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

    // Send the email
    $emailResponse = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);

    // And finally add recipient to a contact list
    $list_id = "123456";
    $recipient_id = base64_encode($recipient);

    $listResponse = $sg->client->contactdb()->lists()->_($list_id)->recipients()->_($recipient_id)->post($request_body);
```